# Android - How to get checked state of CheckBoxes in dynamically added LinearLayouts?

Tags: android, checkbox, android-linearlayout, android-checkbox

I was wondering, I have a vertical LinearLayout where I dynamically add horizontal LinearLayouts.  Each horizontal LinearLayout contains a CheckBox.  I would like to know, how would I retrieve the checked state of each CheckBox in each dynamically added LinearLayout?

```
   for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                    this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            LinearLayout testView = (LinearLayout) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.balance_test_layout, null);
            for (int j = 0; j < customConditions.size(); j++) {
                TextView checkView = new TextView(BalanceActivity.this);
                checkView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
                checkView.setTextSize(20);

                checkView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

                LinearLayout.LayoutParams checkTextParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Math.round(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 45, getResources().getDisplayMetrics())));

                checkTextParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
                checkView.setLayoutParams(checkTextParams);

                testView.addView(checkView);


            }


            CheckBox option = (CheckBox) testView.findViewById(R.id.testCheckBox);
            option.setId(i);
            option.setText(array.get(i));

        //code for of rest of LinearLayout
   }

     okButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        //need to get values of CheckBoxes in here
                    }
     });
```

Comment: You can use getChildAt() (from 0 to getChildCount - 1) of a `LinearLayout`. Then check a class of each element with `instanceof`. If it is a `CheckBox`, do your actions.

Comment: But getChildAt only gets the direct children.  In this case the direct children are LinearLayouts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
     okButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                for (int i = 0; i < testDialogLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    View innerView = testDialogLayout.getChildAt(i);
                    if (innerView instanceof LinearLayout) {
                        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) innerView;
                        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) linearLayout.findViewById(i);

                        //do something with cb

                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: It was simple, yes?